How to get multimodal embeddings from CLIP model?
I'm hoping to use CLIP to get a single embedding for rows of multimodal (image and text) data.
Say I have the following model:
from PIL import Image
import torch
from transformers import CLIPProcessor, CLIPModel
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

model = CLIPModel.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-base-patch32")
processor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-base-patch32")

def convert_image_data_to_tensor(image_data):
    return torch.tensor(image_data)

dataset = df[['image_data', 'text_data']].to_dict('records')

embeddings = []
for data in dataset:
    image_tensor = convert_image_data_to_tensor(data['image_data'])
    text = data['text_data']

    inputs = processor(text=text, images=image_tensor, return_tensors=True)
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(**inputs)

I want to get the embeddings calculated in output. I know that output has the addtributes text_embeddings and image_embeddings, but I'm not sure how they interact later on. If I want to get a single embedding for each record, should I just be concatenating these attributes together? Is there another attribute that combines the two in some other way?
These are the attributes stored in output:
print(dir(output))

['__annotations__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__dataclass_fields__', '__dataclass_params__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__post_init__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'image_embeds', 'items', 'keys', 'logits_per_image', 'logits_per_text', 'loss', 'move_to_end', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'text_embeds', 'text_model_output', 'to_tuple', 'update', 'values', 'vision_model_output']

Also, is there a way to specify the size of the embedding that CLIP outputs? Similar to how you can specify the embedding size in BERT configs?
Thanks in advance for any help here. Feel free to correct me if I'm misunderstanding anything critical here.

CLIP is trained such that the text and image embeddings are projected on to a shared latent space. In fact, image-text similarity is what the model is trained to optimise.
So a very typical use case of CLIP is to compare and match images and text based on similarity. In your case, you don't seem to be interested in any measure of similarity. You already have an image and the text and want some joint embedding representation. So concatenation of the two embeddings the way you described it is fine. An alternative would be take their mean (since they are in the same embedding space, it's fine to do this).
As for the size of the embedding, I don't think there is a way to change it as it's hardwired into the architecture of the model when it's trained. You can perhaps employ a dimensionality reduction technique, or fine tune the model after stacking another fully connected layer with the dimensionality of your choice.

I really appreciate the thorough reply here. Hearing more about what CLIP is doing with these embeddings cleared up a lot. As a follow-up question, if I were to add another fully connected layer to bring down the size of the output space, is that something that would typically require significant training? Or would there be enough going on in the previous frozen layers that my embeddings would work with a fresh FC layer at the end? Sorry if that's a novice question, I'm fairly new to fine-tuning. Cheers.

Yes, since you want the weight updates to happen only on the last layer, it should certainly require much lesser data and training than what the CLIP model itself required. And if your goal is to generate these embeddings for a very specific downstream task, it should be more easy to fine-tune it just for that distribution of data.  But you have to try and see. Also you should consider other dimensionality reduction techniques which are simpler and see if they solve the problem.
